# Can someone explain how to use Nextjs 13.4 Server action with react hook form?

Tags: next.js

I am not able to pass handleSubmit from react hook form to the action attribute.

I can execute the action function without handleSubmit. But in that case, validation and other functionality are not working which I get from react hook form.

Comment: Kindly don't use server action in your project, but if you want to test you free to do it.

Comment: Any particular reason to not use Server Action in the project? We can optimize client-side functionality with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
async function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('username', data.username)
    await handleSubmit(formData)
}
```

Here, `handleSubmit` is your server action and `onSubmit` is your on submit handler.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. In order to utilize RHF you need to call handleSubmit. So when I try handlesubmit(onSubmit) and pass this aync function im not able to append to the formData. I can however do this: console.log(data) and Ill see my object of all my fields.  Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: here's a working example [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-sun-5dnjsy)

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is a wrinkle that is not obvious:  your RHF “onSubmit” function can itself be declared as async.  Then, it can use “await” to invoke server actions (which by definition are async themselves).

Comment: Is it possible to declare both onSubmit and action for the form? Or is it one or the other?

Comment: from what I understand @leafyshark it is one or the other. RHF depends on its onsubmit because thats how its registering all of your inputs.  What I found is that you can call a server action from within your handleSubmit

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/10391#issuecomment-1789632091

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?

I'm using RHF with server action this way

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormTypes> = async data => {
   const formData: FormTypes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
   const request = await serverActionFunction(formData)
   console.log(request)  }
```